# Grouping values in Pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, count

I want to create histogram from my pandas dataframe. I have 1 column, where I save percentage values. I used value_counts() but I have too much percentage values.
Example:

```
0.752        1
0.769        2
0.800        1
0.823        1
          ... 
80.365       1
84.000       1
84.615       1
85.000       10
85.714       1
```

I need to group this values by same rate. For example 5 %. (0 - 4,999 , 5,000 -  9,999, ...) I want this result:

(Example)

```
0  - 4,999       24
5  - 9,999       12
10 - 14,999      30
...
```

Comment: your goal is to only create a histogram? why no to this : `df.plot.hist()`

Comment: because those values are too much, i want to have 10-20 columns in histogram, not 200

Comment: you can pass a 'bins' argument for that, example : `df.plot.hist(bins=20)` will give you an histogram with 20 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group your data by the result of [pd.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
    value  count
0   0.752      1
1  11.769      3
2  22.800      4
3  33.823      5
4  55.365      1
5  84.000      1
6  84.615      1
7  85.000     10
8  99.714      1

In [39]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df.value, bins=np.linspace(0, 100, 21)))['count'].sum().fillna(0)
Out[39]:
value
(0, 5]        1.0
(5, 10]       0.0
(10, 15]      3.0
(15, 20]      0.0
(20, 25]      4.0
(25, 30]      0.0
(30, 35]      5.0
(35, 40]      0.0
(40, 45]      0.0
(45, 50]      0.0
(50, 55]      0.0
(55, 60]      1.0
(60, 65]      0.0
(65, 70]      0.0
(70, 75]      0.0
(75, 80]      0.0
(80, 85]     12.0
(85, 90]      0.0
(90, 95]      0.0
(95, 100]     1.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

alternatively you can drop NaN's:

```
In [40]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df.value, bins=np.linspace(0, 100, 21)))['count'].sum().dropna()
Out[40]:
value
(0, 5]        1.0
(10, 15]      3.0
(20, 25]      4.0
(30, 35]      5.0
(55, 60]      1.0
(80, 85]     12.0
(95, 100]     1.0
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

Explanation:

```
In [41]: pd.cut(df.value, bins=np.linspace(0, 100, 21))
Out[41]:
0       (0, 5]
1     (10, 15]
2     (20, 25]
3     (30, 35]
4     (55, 60]
5     (80, 85]
6     (80, 85]
7     (80, 85]
8    (95, 100]
Name: value, dtype: category
Categories (20, object): [(0, 5] < (5, 10] < (10, 15] < (15, 20] ... (80, 85] < (85, 90] < (90, 95] < (95, 100]]
```

Comment: Looks good. But when I used .value_counts() on my dataframe I have actually dtype: int64 without the names of columns. Can I create new pd dataframe from this chart?

Comment: @Parfi, sure, you can do it this way: `df.col_name.value_counts().reset_index()`

Comment: Work perfect, but those sums are wrong. I dont know why. The result for (0,5] is 5, but it's definitely wrong. Sum will be higher. Where can be possible mistake ?

Comment: can you help me with this problem ?

Comment: @Parfi, sure, i can try, but i need a reproducible sample data set, which would help me to reproduce your problem...

Comment: look on this screenshot: [link](http://prnt.sc/cvdfl1). For example from 95 to 100 are just 2 values, but in the result is the number 27. Why and how ? All sums are wrong.

Comment: @Parfi, how this screenshot should help??? Can you upload somewhere your data as CSV/pickle/etc. file and post here a link?